# KepServerEx connection to Azure IoT Central

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central, kepserverex

I am working on a proof of concept for a monitoring solution and have been able to use the Gateway(Kepserverex) > IoT hub > Power BI model to view my data. The solution works but not scalable so I started looking at Azure IoT Central since it offers an out of the box monitoring solution but what I am struggling with is how can I connect Kepserverex and IoT Central together. I can use MQTT or REST to connect.

Does anyone have any insight into how this can be achieved? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Same as you connect that to iothub. Simply, get your device's `scopeId`, `device Id`, and `Primary or Secondary key` (from the top right Device explorer page - there is button named as `Connect`)

Then you could create the connection string using https://github.com/Azure/dps-keygen

Comment: Thanks Ozzz. I tried doing what you recommended and i am able to provision a device using the dps_cstr but still am not clear on how i can use the information to start sending data to the application using kepserver. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.